# How to get all checked options out of a select form via php through POST?

Tags: php, html

This is driving me nuts. I know there are other questions that addressed this and I think I've pretty much tried everything I've read in them.
Either I'm misunderstanding something very basic or need another pair of eyes on this.

So there's a session already started when this code is being met with the log in credentials and whatnot. I'm trying to get the checked options out of a select form and use them.

```
if(isset($_POST['select']))
{    
    if (is_array($_POST['select'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['select'] as $x)
            echo "<p>$x</p>";
        }
    else {
        echo "<p> There is no selection </p>";
    }
}
```

---

```
 echo <<<_END
 <form method='post' action='profile.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
 <h3>Enter or edit your details </h3>
 <textarea name='text' cols='50' rows='3'>$text</textarea><br />
 <br />
 <span class='fieldname'>YY:</span>
 <select name="select[]"  multiple="multiple" >
 <option value="Opt1"> Choice1</option>
 <option value="Opt2"> Choice2</option>
 <option value="Opt3"> Choice3</option>
 <option value="Opt4"> Choice4</option>
 </select>
 </span><br /><br />

_END;
?>

<input type='submit' value='Save Profile' />
</form></div><br /></body></html>
```

I've only pasted the relevant bits.

When I do my selection and click Save I'm only getting the else branch.

EDIT: It seems that trying with the default encoding on the form did not resolve this issue.

Comment: don't you mean $_POST[] not $_POST{}?

Comment: It is that in the actual code. Typo from copying it here.

Comment: Please everybody keep in mind that I have this exact bit of code, with the same form on another page and it does work. I've tried with empty, is_array, no multiple values. Still can't get ahold of anything in that form. Is the POST data being lost somehow?

Comment: I cannot test this myself, but I think there is a bug or something when transmitting multiple select values with the encoding "multipart/form-data". Would you mind trying without it?

Comment: Well I would need it, since I am having a file input, image and some other text forms on that same page. Would dropping down to GET solve this in any way?

Comment: For file upload, I would suggest using an XMLHttpRequest, then you can also get the progress and stuff :) no need for a form!

Comment: I don't want to use any AJAX on this page. Can I put that select on another form altogether and use a different encoding?

Comment: Have you tried to see if the encoding actually makes a difference? I'm not completely sure if this applies to you.//\

Comment: Testing now...watch this space

Comment: I tried with the default enctype and it didn't make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should make it clear what is happening.

If none of the select options is clicked then there is no entry created in the $_POST array.

the name of 'select[]' tells PHP to convert the input into an array if there is any input selected for this widget.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['select']))
{
    if (is_array($_POST['select'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['select'] as $x)
            echo "<p>$x</p>";
        }
    else { // this cannot happen as nothing comes in when not selected
        echo "<p> There is no selection -- cannot happen</p>";
    }
}
else {
    echo "<p> There is no selection </p>";
}

if (isset($_POST['select'])) {
  var_dump($_POST['select'], 'select'); // you can see what comes in!
}
else {
  echo '<strong>no selected options...</strong>';
}


/*
 * do appropriate 'select' action(s)...
 */
if (isset($_POST['select'])) {

  if (in_array('Opt1', $_POST['select'])) {
     echo '<br/>do Opt1 action...<br/>';
  }

  if (in_array('Opt2', $_POST['select'])) {
     echo '<br/>do Opt2 action...<br/>';
  }

   if (in_array('Opt3', $_POST['select'])) {
     echo '<br/>do Opt3 action...<br/>';
  }

    if (in_array('Opt4', $_POST['select'])) {
     echo '<br/>do Opt4 action...<br/>';
    }
    echo '<br/>';
 }


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Show Select</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="main" id="main">

        <!-- heading -->
        <strong><?php echo 'Select setting...'?></strong><br/>

          <form method='post' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
           <h3>Enter or edit your details </h3>
           <textarea name='text' cols='50' rows='3'>$text</textarea><br />
           <br />
           <span class='fieldname'>YY:</span>
           <select name="select[]"  multiple="multiple" >
           <option value="Opt1"> Choice1</option>
           <option value="Opt2"> Choice2</option>
           <option value="Opt3"> Choice3</option>
           <option value="Opt4"> Choice4</option>
           </select>
           </span><br /><br />

          <input type='submit' value='Save Profile' />
          </form>
    </div><br />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so the only modification is deleting the action value?

Comment: no, you can put your own action in, i just want it to come back to this script. The other change is the else clause on the $_POST test. The code is tested and should work on your system.

Comment: There is no selection --cannot happen string(0) "" string(6) "select" ... What browser are you testing this with?

Comment: I've tried this code as is and it does work. So what was the problem? The php that I'm editing in is quite big so I have to use php interpolation to get my html out. Is it the info in the header?

Comment: "There is no selection --cannot happen string(0) "" string(6) "select" ... What browser are you testing this with?"

It is not possible to get to the inner 'else' clause as there in no 'select' entry in the $_POST array if you do not select any of the widget options.


This is all server side processing. I use firefox and chrome.

Comment: I'm guessing that it's some sort of bug with earlier versions of HTML. Either that or some other widget on that file is throwing things off.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  a foreach

```
if(isset($_POST['select']))
{    
foreach ($_POST['select'] as $x)
        echo "<p>$x</p>";
    }
else {
    echo "<p> There is no selection </p>";
}
}



 <form method='post' action='profile.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
 <h3>Enter or edit your details </h3>
 <textarea name='text' cols='50' rows='3'>$text</textarea><br />
 <br />
 <span class='fieldname'>YY:</span>
 <select name="select"  multiple="multiple" > // remove [] from here //
 <option value="Opt1[]"> Choice1</option>     //change your options to have [] //
 <option value="Opt2[]"> Choice2</option>
 <option value="Opt3[]"> Choice3</option>
 <option value="Opt4[]"> Choice4</option>
 </select>
 </span><br /><br />
```

bassicaly you need to add [] to your options in your select group and take away [] from your select name. And use the code above

Comment: Out of curiosity I tried this with my php. It only keeps the last selection. However, why are they actually permitting this syntax?